# Logical Operators on characters in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

I just wanted to know how R evaluate different characters when applied logical operators. Like

```
"a" > "b"
"b" > "c"
"a+b" > "b+a"
"-" > "+"
"&" > "%"
```

I just wanted to know how R arrange different symbols and characters in ascending or descending order? My prior belief was "NA" for each operation defined above. But R returns either TRUE or FALSE for each and every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the help page for Comparison `?Comparison`

To quote the key passage:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising. Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it follows g. Some platforms may not respect the locale and always sort in numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in Unicode code-point order for a UTF-8 locale (and may not sort in the same order for the same language in different character sets). Collation of non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens, fractions and so on) is even more problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this conundrum by explicitly requesting the order of a list of char or string values...

```
items <- c('+','-','a','z', 'A', 'a+b', 'a+x', '*', '/')
items[order(items)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sort` you can get the order.

```
sort(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9, "+", "\"", "¦", "@", "*", "#", "ç", "%", "&", "¬", "|",
"(", "¢", ")", "=", "?", "'", "´", "`", "^", "~", "!", "[", "]", "$", "£", "{", "}", 
".", ",", "-", "_", "<", ">", "/"))
```

Comment: But what is criteria for arranging such characters in R?

Comment: First symbols, then digits then letters wheres small comes before capital when it is the same letter. The order of symbols depends on your local settings. (Also see answer from @Stephen Henderson)